# Filtering xml file on attributes on similarly named elements using linq to xml

Tags: c#-4.0, attributes, linq-to-xml

I suppose the solution is simple, but I haven't found an answer despite searching the internet extensively. Please help! The problem is : my xml query is not returning the required result if the required attribute is not inside the first  element of similarly named elements. For example, this code is not returning anything:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("~/Employees.xml"));
        var homePhone = from phoneno in xelement.Elements("Employee")
               where (string)phoneno.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type") == "Work"
        select phoneno;
foreach (XElement xEle in homePhone)
        TextBox1.Text= xEle + "/n";
```

However, if I substitute "Work" with "Home", I get the required result. In fact, I should get exactly the same result with "Work". Can someone please explain how to do this?

The xml template is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
      <City>Acampo</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Name>Lucy</Name>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Other">143-555-0763</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">434-555-0567</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>Jess Bay</Street>
      <City>Alta</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95701</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>3</EmpId>
    <Name>Kate</Name>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Home">166-555-0231</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Other">233-555-0442</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>23 Boxen Street</Street>
      <City>Milford</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>96121</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>4</EmpId>
    <Name>Chris</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Work">564-555-0122</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Other">442-555-0154</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>124 Kutbay</Street>
      <City>Montara</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>94037</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XElement.Element("name") will return the FIRST element of the given name when there is more than one.  You really want this:

```
var employeesWithHomePhone = from e in xdocument.Root.Elements("Employee")
                             where e.Elements("Phone").Any( p => (string)p.Attribute("Type") == "Home") 
                             select e;
```

And just change "Home" to "Work" to get the ones with a Work number

Comment: There is no Elements method in IEnumerable

Comment: Sorry I got my code a little mixed up. A correction to my earlier code. Instead of "select phoneno.Element("Phone");", it should read "select phonono;" Then my question makes sense. Can you check it now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to query, can you explain in English rather than source code?

Comment: I have modified the original template's attributes to make the question clearer. The question is, "get me the employee elements where the employee has a 'Home' phone number". The next query is to get me the employee elements where the employee has a 'Work' phone number. Using my query, I get employee ids 1 and 3 for 'Home', which is correct. But I get only employee id 4 for 'Work', whereas I should be getting employee ids 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: It worked like a charm and answered the question comprehensively. Thanks, that was awesome! Can you explain what "=>" stands for or where I can study it further? That's a new symbol for me.

Comment: That is a C# lambda expression, essentially an anonymous callback function that is being passed to Any, which calls it back to evaluate whether any of the phone elements meet your criteria.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
where (string)phoneno.Element("Phone")
```

is indeed using only the first Phone element since you requested only one. You need to use the `Elements` method, but you can iterate all phones instead of employees:

```
from phone in xelement.Descendants("Phone")
where (string)phone.Attribute("Type") == "Work"
select phone;
```

If you want to make sure this phone belongs to an employee add this condition in the `where`:

```
phone.Parent.Name == "Employee"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result does not give the xml tree starting with the "Employee" tag, which is what I need as I would like to save it as an xml file. I do get the xml tree if I query the "Home" attribute.

Comment: <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">434-555-0567</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">233-555-0442</Phone>
<Phone Type="Work">442-555-0154</Phone>

Comment: <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone> <Phone Type="Work">434-555-0567</Phone> <Phone Type="Work">233-555-0442</Phone> <Phone Type="Work">442-555-0154</Phone>